# Amazon AWS SQS Java - Attributes Null

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, attributes, amazon-sqs

I am trying to pull AWS SQS Message attributes from each message that is process. I have verified that the attribute is there and everything is spelled correctly:
Name: RequestId
Value: thisistherequestid

I get messages this way:

```
messages = sqs.receiveMessage(request.withQueueUrl(queueUrl).withAttributeNames("All")).getMessages()
```

I have also tried:

```
messages = sqs.receiveMessage(request.withQueueUrl(queueUrl).withAttributeNames("RequestId")).getMessages()
```

I have tried the two things but it just comes back null every time.

```
        for (Message m : messages) {
            Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> attributeValues = new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();
            attributeValues = m.getMessageAttributes();
            System.out.println("Attribute Values ===>  " + attributeValues.get("RequestId").getStringValue());
```

I also tried:

```
        for (Message m : messages) {
            Map<String, String> attributeValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
            attributeValues = m.getAttributes();
            System.out.println("Attribute Values ===>  " + attributeValues.get("RequestId"));
```

I'm not quite sure what is going wrong here.. even if u just do this the attributes are empty:

```
            attributeValues = m.getMessageAttributes();
            System.out.println("Attribute Values ===>  " + attributeValues);
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Here is what I see in the AWS Console:

[image]

Comment: When you say "I have verified that the attribute is there", what do you mean?  Did you verify it through the AWS console?

Comment: Yeah, I have two messages I can see on the AWS Console. I can process them fine using the SQS SDK for Java. But no matter what I do, the Attributes are empty. I can click on the Message Attributes tab and verify that there are attributes.  **Updated to show Message Attribute Tab.

Comment: And you've verified that the `queueUrl` you're using in your code is the same one that shows up on the SQS console when you select the queue name?  Your code looks good to me (other than you don't need to allocate `attributeValues` - that's thrown away on the next line) so I'm looking for other issues.

Comment: Yep... it processes and deletes the messages without difficulty. All of that is fine. It's just these darned message attributes. I cannot for the life of me see why this is failing. If I use getAttributes() it gets those fine.. but getMessageAttributes() always returns nothing.

Comment: Got it... there was a comment buried on the AWS Website. When you set up your ReceiveMessageRequest object, you have to specify both withMessageAttributeNames("RequestId") AND withAttributeNames("")... even if the second one you just add empty quotes to.  That is extremely whacky.   3+ hours later.........

Answer (score 0):

What you have set is message attribute in sqs. So while retrieving you have to the below code.

```
messages = sqs.receiveMessage(request.withQueueUrl(queueUrl).withMessageAttributeNames("RequestId")).getMessages()
```

This will fetch the message attribute with name `RequestId`